# git amend and merge a commit which is not in master

Tags: git

I'll keep it short.

**Usecase:**

> One of my devs has pushed a commit let's say "A" (Which is Unmerged)
>
> I want to take that commit (unmerged) and I want to add changes to
>   them. Modify them and push my own commit. (Commit B) (Which includes
>   commit A)

**How can I do that? How can I push my commit and HIS commit together?**

PS:

I tried to `git checkout` his commit and made my changes but when I do `git commit` it does not work (Since his commit is unmerged).

Comment: @BryceDrew I don't see how the link is relevant to my problem. The link talks about merge conflict. but in this case I don't have a conflict, nor did the first commit was merged.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want to merge his change into your local branch, and then modify the change (in your branch) before later merging to `master` or `trunk` or some other upstream branch.

Assuming your branch and his have common history (eg, your branch is already at the change before his change, and his change is a single change), you need just a simple "git merge --ff-only".  You can then edit things (still in your branch) and do a "git commit --amend" to modify that last change.  You can then (later) merge the change from your local branch elsewhere.

If your branch is not in sync with the state before his branch (and can't easily be made to be), or if there is more than one change, things will be more difficult.  You might be able to use "git cherry-pick" usefully, depending on your exact situation.